# SQL SUM and DISTINCT two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, subquery, distinct

I have a table called points and based on distinct values of entires, I want to sum valid entries.

I have this:

| valid_entries | Codes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 768 |
| 2 | 1224 |
| 2 | 1224 |
| 1 | 512 |
| 1 | 512 |

Based on distinct values I would have:

| valid_entries | codes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 768 |
| 2 | 1224 |
| 1 | 512 |

I want to get the sum of valid_entries that would be 4.

I have tried this one and I have  PostgreSQL 11.5 version and I am new to this. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help with this.

```
SELECT sum(valid_entries) FROM 
(SELECT count(distinct(codes)) FROM points WHERE  participant_id='123') t
```

Comment: Have you tried using group by? SELECT sum(valid_entries),codes FROM points WHERE  participant_id='123' GROUP BY [codes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter out the duplicate rows with `DISTINCT` and then aggregate:

```
SELECT SUM(valid_entries) total
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT valid_entries, Codes FROM points WHERE participant_id='123') t;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2d0febac63b54fdbeef0852072fbc7e0).